# fantasy book about a boy drowning in ice and waking up in a fantasy world

Tags: story-identification, books

I've been trying to remember the title of this fantasy book. I believe it was from the early 90's.

It was about a human boy who was at a party, gets in trouble with some rough teenagers and gets chased out onto some ice. He falls through and as he is drowning gets sucked into a magical world. There he meets a girl and a guy who help him understand the world he is in where people from other worlds end up. Also they have to overcome trials, like his drowning.  Then there is a girl who is claustrophobic, and also I think a guy with a fear of fire.

Comment: I think I recall this book.  Didn't the characters get magical equipment, like boots that let them cover the distance of ten steps in a single stride?  If I recall, it was written by a teen who died, and his favorite author (at his request) polished it up and published it under his name.

Comment: Yeah, I just re-read this recently.  It's absolutely *Through the Ice*.

Answer (score 9):

Could it be [Through the Ice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0671721135) by Robert Kornwise and Piers Anthony?

From Amazon:

> **Book Description**
>
> **Publication Date:** April 1, 1992
>
> One minute Seth was
>   fighting for his life against a gang of teenage punks in Michigan, the
>   next he had fallen through the ice--into another, magical Earth. Seth,
>   along with a telepath, a faun, and a giant have been chosen from four
>   different Earth planes to fulfill a quest in a world of magic.

Comment: Late comment on this, but the publishing history of this is interesting in that Robert Kornwise wrote most of the book before suffering from a fatal automobile accident at 16 whereupon his friends sent the manuscript to Piers Anthony, his favorite author, with a request to complete and publish it.